# Express.js Have a button initiate a download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm playing around with express, but am having trouble getting html forms to submit queries.

I have this snippet of code that should serve a random image and a button that should download it.

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res, next){
    src = req.query.src;
    console.log(req.query);
    res.download('/images/' + src);
});
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.body = "<h1>Random art: </h1><br />";
    res.body = res.body + "<img src='";
    image = returnRandomImagePath();
    res.body = res.body + image;
    res.body = res.body + "' height = '300' width = '300' />";
    res.body = res.body + "<form action = '/download?src=" + image + "' method = 'GET'>";
    res.body = res.body + "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Download' />";
    res.body = res.body + "</form>";
    res.body = res.body + "<br />";
    res.send(res.body);
});
```

but when I click on the button on the page, I get

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/images/[object Object]'
>       at Error (native)"

and the console logs that req.query was empty.

Edit: Code for returnRandomImagePath():

```
const images = ["image1.jpg",
                "image2.jpg",
                "image3.jpg",
                "image4.jpg",
                "image5.jpg",
                "image6.jpg",
                "image7.jpg",
                "image8.jpg",
                "image9.jpg"];

function returnRandomImagePath() {
    min = Math.ceil(0);
    max = Math.floor(images.length-1);
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
    return(images[number]);
}
```

Comment: And please use templates

Comment: returnRandomImagePath() just returns a string with an image filename, such as image1.jpg. I want to send this through the query to build the filename in the /download middleware.

Comment: Can you log `src` ?
Also, can you provide us `returnRandomImagePath` code ?

Comment: Added code for `returnRandomImagePath()`. src logs as `undefined`, req.query logs as `{}`.

Comment: As a side note, `returnRandomImagePath` can be factorized like this : `return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];` since `min` is 0, and `max` is equal to `images.length - 1 - 0 + 1`, so basically `images.length`. Is the url inside the `form` well formed in your browser ?

Comment: Can you check the rendered html is `<form action = '/download?src="imageX.jpg" method = 'GET'>`or not?

Comment: It renders as `<form action="/download?src=&quot;image1.jpg&quot;" method="GET">`

Answer (score -1):

try using app.get('*') instead of app.get('/')

Comment: I don't think this have anything to do wth the problem, since OP can access his page.